# Given a Timezone offset, what are the matching Timezones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

Given an offset, how to query for the matching timezones?

Example: `-05:00`

Should return `AMT` and `EDT` (along with the others)

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We'd like to see an example of the code you wrote trying to solve this along with an explanation why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, this question is not answerable.

However, one can ask any of the following:

- Which time zones might be using this offset *now?*
- Which time zones might have used this offset *at some other specific date and time in the past?*
- Which time zones might be predicted to use this offset *at some other specific date and time in the future?*
- Which time zones have ever used this offset *at any point in time?*

Those are all different questions, and for many offsets you won't get a single answer from any of them.

Also, you appear to be asking for time zone abbreviations, which could also be ambiguous.  For example, `CST` has five possible interpretations, `IST` has three, etc.

See also [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.select{ |tz| tz.formatted_offset.eql?('-05:00') }.map(&:now)
```

Comment: Since Rails includes ActiveSupport (per OPs tags) `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.select{ |tz| tz.formatted_offset.eql?('-05:00') }`